# Use Makefile to convert postcript files to PDF and keep them updated?

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have 100 .ps files in a directory, called doc1.ps, doc2.ps, ... , doc100.ps. I would like to write a Makefile to do the following: (1) when I run "make", all the files matching the pattern doc*.ps should be converted to the pdf format (without deleting the original copy) using the command line program ps2pdf. (2) Any .ps files not matching the name pattern doc*.ps should be left untouched. (3) Whenever a file doc*.ps is updated, running "make" again should only update the PDF copy of this specific file, without converting all of them again. How can this be done?

P.S. I don't want to type the names of the .ps files explicitly into the Makefile, because this is tedious when there are many files. I'd like to have Makefile handle the matching of wildcard filenames.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of things make is made for. What did you try up to now, and why aren't you satisfied with it?

Comment: +1 for the first comment. A simple Makefile can do nearly everything described, but you'll probably need additions to preserve or custom-rename existing output .pdf files. Let me know if you want a starter Makefile posted.